# How to make Bootstrap Tour apply GET parameters

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, get, bootstrap-tour

I have a search system where the homepage is at:

```
http://example.com/
```

And the results page (which are totally different) are at:

```
http://example.com/?q=foo
```

I'm trying to set up bootstrap tour so that it begins on the homepage and then takes the user to a result page. So I have steps like:

```
        {
            path: '/',
            element: "#extra-sidebar-fields",
            backdrop: true,
            title: "Sophisticated Search",
            content: "In the Advanced Search area, you can make sophisticated searches against many fields. " +
                "Press \"Next\" and we'll make a query for you.",
        },
        {
            path: '/?q=roe+v+wade',
            element: 'article:first',
            title: 'Detailed Results',
            content: 'Here you can see the results for the query "Roe v Wade" sorted by relevance.'
        }
```

The problem I encounter is that the tour doesn't understand that it needs to perform the GET request to load the second step, so I suppose I need to use the `redirect` key or something.

If I had search results at a different path, this would work marvellously, but since the homepage and the results are both at `/`, it appears I'm stuck.

### Edits...

Working in the open, I've tried a few things since posting this. First, I thought I might be able to accomplish the redirect by using the onNext parameter, so I changed my first step to have:

```
     {
        path: '/',
        element: "#extra-sidebar-fields",
        backdrop: true,
        title: "Sophisticated Search",
        content: "In the Advanced Search area, you can make sophisticated searches against many fields. " +
            "Press \"Next\" and we'll make a query for you.",
        onNext: function(){
            window.location = '/?q=row+v+wade'
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/?q=roe+v+wade',
        element: 'article:first',
        title: 'Detailed Results',
        content: 'Here you can see the results for the query "Roe v Wade" sorted by relevance.'
    }
```

That didn't work though because while the redirect happened properly (good!), before it did the user would see the next step pop up, and depending on their connection speed, it could be visible for a while before the redirect finished. So that strategy is no good unless I can prevent the next step from popping up.

---

I tried another strategy, redefining the _isRedirect method:

```
tour._isRedirect = function(path, currentPath){
    return (path != null) && //Return false if path is undefined.
        path !== "" && (
        ({}.toString.call(path) === "[object RegExp]" && !path.test(currentPath)) ||
            ({}.toString.call(path) === "[object String]" &&
                path.replace(/\/?$/, "") !== currentPath.replace(/\/?$/, "")
                )
        );
}
```

Normally it has a line in there that strips out the GET parameters (`path.replace(/\?.*$/, "")`), so I modified it not to do that. This change also sort of worked. The redirect happened properly without showing the next step, but unfortunately this change made it have a redirect loop...or something like that. It just kept redirecting over and over.

---

Not sure what I'll do next. Could use the help of somebody more savvy in the ways of JS.

Comment: I have a feeling that BS tour is just not meant to be used this way.  A tour normally hops over elements on a single page, and having it perform full page reload would seem rather strange.

Comment: No, it has support for multipage via the path attribute, but it doesn't seem to support GET params.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line number 431 to this

```
   return (path != null) && path !== "" && (({}.toString.call(path) === "[object RegExp]" && !path.test(currentPath)) || ({}.toString.call(path) === "[object String]" && path !== currentPath));
```

By default that line strips out the "?" for both currentPath and path. So when `path = "/?q=roe+v+wade"` and `currentPath = "/"` the `q=roe+v+wade` is stripped, so the path and currentPath are equal therefore the redirect is not initiated.

Edit: found an issue with my initial answer. Update line 292 to

```
    current_path = [document.location.pathname, document.location.search, document.location.hash].join("");
```

The current_path variable (that is fed into the isRedirect function) originally only gets the pathname and the hash. The addition of document.location.search tells it to grab the get vars as well -- I must say though, that I'm not 100% sure of the browser compatibility.